# Use awk on an Android command

Tags: awk, adb

I have an Android command whose output is as follows:

```
$adb shell "head -20 /d/dma_buf/bufinfo"

Dma-buf Objects:
size            flags           mode            count           exp_name        buf name
00020480        00000002        00000007        00000003        ion-system-660-vendor.qti.hard  dmabuf210
        Attached Devices:
Total 0 devices attached

09469952        00000002        00000007        00000003        ion-system-660-vendor.qti.hard  dmabuf209
        Attached Devices:
        kgsl-3d0
Total 1 devices attached

00020480        00000002        00000007        00000003        ion-system-660-vendor.qti.hard  dmabuf208
        Attached Devices:
Total 0 devices attached

09469952        00000002        00000007        00000003        ion-system-660-vendor.qti.hard  dmabuf207
        Attached Devices:
        kgsl-3d0
Total 1 devices attached
```

There are similar entries in the file. Now what I want is to extract the pid from the exp_name field (kernel doesn't have access to the complete name that's greater than 16 bytes) and get that process's complete name from the ps output with `ps pid -o comm=` cf. [1] and print it along with `$1` of the awk output.  I am stuck at how to retrieve that. I started with the following command

```
$adb shell "sed -n '/dmabuf/p' /d/dma_buf/bufinfo|head -10"|awk '
BEGIN { touch temp} {echo $5 > temp; pid = $(cut -d '-' -f 3,3 temp);}
END { rm temp}
'
```

But this yields syntax errors as:

```
awk: cmd. line:2: BEGIN { touch temp} {echo $5 > temp; pid = $(cut -d - -f 3,3 temp);}
awk: cmd. line:2:                                                           ^ syntax error
```

[1] There's a problem with Android awk due to which I'm resorting to the host Linux machine's utilities.

```
$adb shell "awk '/dmabuf/{print}' /d/dma_buf/bufinfo|head -3"
00020480        00000002        00000007        00000003        ion-system-660-vendor.qti.hard  dmabuf210
09469952        00000002        00000007        00000003        ion-system-660-vendor.qti.hard  dmabuf209
00020480        00000002        00000007        00000003        ion-system-660-vendor.qti.hard  dmabuf208

adb shell "awk '/dmabuf/{print NF}' /d/dma_buf/bufinfo|head -3"
6
6
6
```

So this output has 6 fields (that are tab separated). Yet when I try to print the individual fields it doesn’t do that and still prints the entire line.

```
$adb shell "awk '/dmabuf/{print $4}' /d/dma_buf/bufinfo|head -3"
00020480        00000002        00000007        00000003        ion-system-660-vendor.qti.hard  dmabuf210
09469952        00000002        00000007        00000003        ion-system-660-vendor.qti.hard  dmabuf209
00020480        00000002        00000007        00000003        ion-system-660-vendor.qti.hard  dmabuf208
```

Comment: **a)** there is **no problem** with android's `awk`; the `$4` in your last command will be expanded (to nothing) by the shell on the PC, because it's inside double quotes. **b)** you cannot do shell-like command expansion inside `awk` (use `split()` instead of `$(cut -d ...)` **c)** android has `pgrep -l`

Comment: @mosvy What would you recommend then for fixing my command to work using the Android awk ? I tried `adb shell awk /dmabuf/'{print $4}' /d/dma_buf/bufinfo|head -10` but that gives an error `awk: illegal statement at source line 1
        missing }`.

Comment: `adb shell 'awk '\''/dmabuf/{print $4}'\'' /d/dma_buf/bufinfo'`. I cannot give you a turnkey answer, because on my all android devices, that `bufinfo` file has a completely different format.

Comment: @mosvycan you please explain the syntax you've used or direct me to something that might clarify my queries since I suspect there's something basic that I'm missing.

Comment: yes you are missing something basic -- the fact that variables (eg. `$4`) are expanded by the shell inside double quotes, and that the argument to `adb shell` will be expanded *twice* (by the shell on the PC and by the shell on the android gadget). I suggest you use `set -x` liberally until you figure out what happens: `(set -x; adb shell 'set -x; ...')`.

Comment: There is a clever (or sneaky) solution because in shell `$onedigit` is special _syntax_ for a positional argument, but in awk `$number` is an _operator_ applied to a value (even an expression), thus `adb shell 'awk "/dmabuf/ { print $ 4 }" filename'` (note inserted space) (@mosvy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm able to extract the `pid`s with:

```
$ awk 'NF == 6 {print $5}' inputfile | grep -Eo '[0-9]+'
660
660
660
660
```

Since Android uses `procfs`, you can see the actual binary as a symlink in `/proc/$pid/exe`.  But, since this is a magic (i. e. `procfs`) symlink that doesn't obey the normal POSIX rules, you can't use the more common methods to find its target.  You can, however, use `stat`:

```
$ stat -c '%N' /proc/$$/exe
`/proc/4811/exe' -> `/system/bin/sh'
[...]
```

Answer (score -1):

line # specifications for specific file info extraction.And syntax patterns|actions rule. awk is continuous oneline script altho wrapped. just write a `$` and the #1-16, of the system info code obtained from gawk. get the guide on playstore maybe and get used to it. its an excellent scripting language. and awk is open source if you want to rename a # you can alter the code at any time to fit your information needs.

```
$0 = all
$1 = 1st field
$2 = 2nd field
etc.,
$NF =the last field
```

now you need actions,
so type a `|` and specify which info you want from which fields in fancy bracets and the entire thing in single quotes...idk about including `---BEGIN`. awk doesnt need it on android,,,but i could just have more priv on my phone than im aware of also..good luck i like the gawk= guide for awk..simplicity at its rock bottom best.